# Route error on showing utf8 filename photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have moved my Rails App to another server, where ruby version is `2.2.6p396`, instead of `2.2.0p0` also newer passenger+nginx. But maybe it is problem not because of software.

I have a photo with utf8 filename in my public dir, when entering this url to browser `http://localhost/app/my_photos/small.Braškės.jpg`

It worked fine on previous server, now I got an error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "...
```

If I change filename removing utf8 chars, then it works well:

```
http://localhost/app/my_photos/small.Braskes.jpg
```

But I need it working with utf8 chars.